# How to compute the $\liminf$ of the given series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

How do I compute $$\liminf_{k \to \infty}\frac{\log \sqrt{(x_1)^{2^{k+1}}+(x_2)^{2^{k+1}}+(x_3)^{2^{k+1}}+(x_4)^{2^{k+1}}+(x_5)^{2^{k+1}}+(x_6)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k},$$ where $x_i$ are arbitrary real numbers?

I can only think of L'Hospital's law, but it seems hard to compute.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that
all the $x_i$ are positive,
since they are all raised 
to an even power.

Let
$z$ be the largest
of all the $x_i$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{\log \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}
&=\frac{\log \sqrt{z^{2^{k+1}}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i/z)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}\\
&=\frac{\log z^{2^k}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i/z)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}\\
&=\frac{\log z^{2^k}+\log\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i/z)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}\\
&=\frac{2^k\log z+\log\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i/z)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}\\
&=\log z+\frac{\log\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i/z)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}\\
\end{array}
$

Since each
$x_i/z \le 1$,
$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i/z)^{2^{k+1}}
\le n$,
so
$|\frac{\log \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)^{2^{k+1}}}}{2^k}-\log z|
\le \frac{\log\sqrt{n}}{2^k}
\to 0
$
for large $k$.

So the limit,
not just the lim inf,
is $\log z$.

Comment: We can also show that if $(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence with $z=\sup_i| x_i|$ then $z=\lim_{k\to \infty}2^{-k}\log \sqrt {   \sum_{i\in \mathbb N}   x_i^{2^{k+1}}    }.$

Comment: You have to be careful because now it is a double limit. For example, suppose the sequence is constant. Also, that should be log z, not just z.

Comment: Yes it should be $\log z$ in my comment. Another one like it is: If $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and non-negative then $\lim_{n\to \infty }(\int_0^1[f(x)]^n\;dx)^{1/n}=\max f(x).$